# How does the Sonarqube Gradle Plugin locate test resources

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, gradle-plugin

I have a Java project setup with submodules:

```
cool-as-winter
    snowman
        src
            main
            test
            integrationTest
    snow-plower
        src
            main
            test
            integrationTest
    iceman
        src
            main
            test
            integrationTest
                com
                    example
                       AntiFreezeTest.java
```

My build.gradle at the root project level:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "Cool Service"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "com.example:cool-as-winter"  
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test, src/integrationTest"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "$buildDir/jacoco/text.exec, $buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"
        property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "$buildDir/classes/integrationTest, $buildDir/classes/test"
    }
}
```

But, when I run the `sonar` task I get "Resource Not Found: com.example.AntiFreezeTest.com"

Comment: Does the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle) not providing some help?

Comment: Nope. At least it doesn't seem to work as the instructions imply.